# Best way to compare querysets against a queryset

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have a queryset that I want to compare with querysets.

Say I have queryset like this:

```
x = Thing.objects.get(user=request.user).thing_response.all()
```

Then I have querysets that fetches every "Thing" and related response like this

```
all = Things.objects.all()
i = [x.id for x in all.thing_response.all()]
```

I have built a list of ids with x and i. Now I want to get an exact match of i in x: it works for small data, but when data grows matching stops.

I use set for matching: `if set(x) == set(i)` in a loop

but it doesn't work when the data gets large. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question very well but one way to compare these two lists is to use something like:

```
x = []
try:
    x = Thing.objects.get(
        user=request.user
        ).thing_response.values_list('id', flat=True)
except Thing.DoesNotExist:
    pass
except Thing.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    pass
```

and then to retrieve the list of all `thing_response` ids use:

```
i = Thing.objects.filter(
    thing_response__isnull=False
    ).values_list('thing_response__id', flat=True)
```

Note 1: If you're sure that only one item exists per this query (i.e. `Thing.objects.get`) you can get rid of the exception handling part.

Note 2: The `thing_response__isnull=False` will exclude the items that do not have any relation with `thing_response`.

and finally to compare these two lists:

```
if set(x) == set(i):
    print('Given lists are equal')
```